# SQL Server 2016 users who have purchased more than one type of pass

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to find out the users who have purchased more than one type of pass. Not how many passes they have purchased.

My query is:

```
select 
    MemberNameFormatted, 
    passtype
from
    Memberships_View_With_Inactive As members
inner join 
    PassType AS PassType on PassType.serviceguid = members.ServiceGUID
where 
    PassType in ('Fee Assistance Pass', 'All Access','Plus Pass','Value Pass')
group by 
    MemberNameFormatted, PassType
having 
    count(all(PassType)) >= 1
```

This returns and shows me all the users and the type of pass type they hold:

[image]

What I need is: only those users who have held two or more different pass types:

[image]

A person can renew their membership every month, so I am not interested in how many memberships they have just if they have held a different one at any time.  Most people stick to the one type of pass so there are thousands of entries in the membership table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` if you just want the members (as your question states):

```
select m.MemberNameFormatted, pt.passtype
from Memberships_View_With_Inactive m join
     PassType pt
     on pt.serviceguid = m.ServiceGUID
where pt.PassType in ('Fee Assistance Pass', 'All Access', 'Plus Pass', 'Value Pass')
group by m.MemberNameFormatted
having count(distinct pt.passtype) >= 2
```

If you want the passes too, then:

```
with mp as (
      select m.MemberNameFormatted, pt.passtype
      from Memberships_View_With_Inactive m join
           PassType pt
           on pt.serviceguid = m.ServiceGUID
      where pt.PassType in ('Fee Assistance Pass', 'All Access', 'Plus Pass', 'Value Pass')
     )
select distinct mp.*
from mp
where exists (select 1
              from mp mp2
              where mp2.MemberNameFormatted= mp.MemberNameFormatted and mp2.passtype <> mp.passtype
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join with a distinct

```
select distinct
   t1.MemberNameFormatted, 
   t1.passtype
from
   Table as t1
join
   Table as t2 on
   t2.MemberNameFormatted = t1.MemberNameFormatted and
   t2.passtype <> t1.passtype
order by
   t1.MemberNameFormatted, 
   t1.passtype
```